# Access variable in nested parfor loop in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, parallel-processing, parfor

Consider the following code in MATLAB:

```
function parallelProblem
N = 10;
A = rand(N);
parfor i=1:N
    for k=2:N
        A(i,k) = f(A(i,k-1));
     end
end

end

function y=f(x)
y = x;
end
```

This is a summary of the problematic code I'm working on. Basically the idea is the following: I have to variables `i`and `k`and I can perform my computation with no communication between different `i`, but communication between different values of `k`is required.

Therefore I want to parallelize the loop over `i`.  However, for the code above I get the error

```
parallelProblem

Error: File: parallelProblem.m Line: 6 Column: 9
The variable A in a parfor cannot be classified.
See Parallel for Loops in MATLAB, "Overview".
```

Hovering over the word parfor (which is underlined) gives

```
The PARFOR loop can not run due to the way the variable 'A' is used.
```

and hovering over `f(A(i,k-1))` gives

```
Valid indices for 'A' are restricted in PARFOR loops
```

and

```
In PARFOR loop, variable 'A' is indexed in different ways, potentially causing dependencies between iterations.
```

From an intuitive point of view, I see no reason why the code should be working in parallel. Is there any way, I can modify my code to get the desired result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are overwriting `A`. Loops in a `parfor` are not executed in order and MATLAB sees that you are overwriting the values of A, and then using them. You can easily fix this using an auxiliary variable:

```
function parallelProblem

N = 5;
A = magic(N);
Aresult=[];
parfor i=1:N,N
    b=[];
    for k=2:N
        b(k) = f(A(i,k-1));
    end
   Aresult(i,:)=b;
end

end
```

Comment: Thanks for the fix. This seems to work. However, I thought overwriting values wouldn't be a problem, since I overwrite values that are only used inside the same `n`iteration. There is no communication between different `n`and I only write in the part of the variable that is read by the `n` that is also writing. Or is MATLAB unable to distinguish this from a case where this is not the setting?

Comment: @k1next I think in this case its just MATLAB being completely unable to distinguish.

Comment: Thanks! That helped.